# What are your thoughts on approaching UX from a coding background?

Tags: ux-designer, learning

This is not a tech question but is more related to knowing prototyping apps and approaching UX from a coding background.

What are people's experience with having to be familiar with or understand an app like Sketch, etc.? Or even just approaching UX and app design from the larger perspective beyond coding. Is it good to combine the two? My concern is spreading myself too thing considering the challenges of mastering the technical demands of coding.

Eventually I'd like to get into app design, etc., but the coding aspect has been enough to handle on its own. However it does seem to be a useful to learn both aspects. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question fits the format of StackExchange, but if you have an account on Reddit, we are having many discussions like this on [r/userexperience](https://www.reddit.com/r/userexperience/) and you're welcome to ask this there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fair question. Engineering is a step after UX however, so while yes the two jobs are absolutely enough for one person to do just one, there are plenty of examples of people who have done everything (including more than just UX and coding).

I've been fortunate enough to successfully graduate dozens of engineers in multiple UX courses. They typically make for excellent UXDs because they understand the underlying code, which makes a big difference in a practical sense for constructing apps and websites. So it is good to combine the two; the more I've learned about both engineering practices and thinking, the better I've become in my UX work as well.

My recommendation is consider the product you're building and why it matters. Then you can choose your route: build it and see what happens, and improve the experience along the way, or start researching the needs and save yourself some time and hassle by going through the UX process, and then start coding when things are already organized. It's going to be more work than just coding, but it'll be less work than coding a product by yourself and then hoping it all works out.

Comment: Thank you.  That was insightful.